# pseudo selector for uppercase chars/words?

Tags: css, css-selectors, uppercase, capitalization

Is there a CSS pseudoselector for uppercase characters/letters/words? I want all my capitals to be a pt smaller and all the other characters the same size. A capital is not neccesarily the first character of a sentence (or word) nor the other way around.

Or maybe there's another way to find these characters in CSS? With a trick? I like tricks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there's the poor-supported [first-letter](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstletter) selector, but that's not what you want.

You could of course also pre-parse your HTML in PHP, wrapping all caps in `<span class="capital"></span>` tags, but that's a hack.

Then of course you could always pull out the magic jQuery rabbit and alter your DOM at document load to include the spans. That's also a hack. Do you like hacks?

Let's see who else turns up with a magic trick :-)

Comment: I like hacks, but not jQuery and not Javascript to fix style things. Preparsing in PHP is a good idea. Good thing I'm using PHP :)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible.

Better to just wrap the capital letters with a span with a class and use that to style them.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using CSS.

You could use Javascript to check all characters in your text for uppercase (e.g. by using `if (yourtext == yourtext.toUpperCase())`) and then wrap a `<span>` around them containing your CSS to style these.

Or something around these lines:

```
function wrapCaps() {
    var text = document.getElementById("my_text").value;
    for(i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if(text[i].charCodeAt(text[i]) >= 65 && text[i].charCodeAt(text[i]) <= 90)
        wrapNode(text[i], 'span');
    }
}
```

I didn't try it out (maybe somebody has the time to create a jsfiddle with this?), you might need to use `replaceNode` or something like that. The `charCodeAt` method just looks for uppercase letters, please note that no unicode characters like special greek uppercase letters will be included.
You now only need to style your span with something like:

```
#my_text span {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I don't use javascript for layout/style fixes. I like pure. Nice of you to work out the function though!